# Opencv image shape tuple unpacking

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

```
# Importing the libraries
import numpy as np
import cv2


# Load two images
img1 = cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\user1\Pictures\messi.jpg')
img2 = cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\user1\Pictures\opencvimp.jpg')
# I want to put logo on top-left corner, So I create a ROI
rows,cols,channels = img2.shape
```

this above code is giveing me the following error.

```
rows,cols,channels = img2.shape
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape
```

What am I doing wrong with img2.shape ?

Answer (score 1):

the `img2` is `None`. It looks like the file is not a valid image

Comment: Thanks. Actually I was trying to implement the code given in 'Bitwise Operation' section of this url... So I downloaded two images from internet and started in Spyder. https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_core/py_image_arithmetics/py_image_arithmetics.html

I changed the image formar from JPG to PNG. I opened the image in MS Paint and saved the image in 'png' format. Then tried the the following code. But still the same error

img2 = cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\user1\Pictures\opencvimp.png')
Error:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape

Comment: Hello @Marat. You are correct indeed. I gave the wrong picture name.